# C# / Linq - Query returns the current ApplicationUser and leaves the other ones null

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have a bridge table connecting a sender and a receiver. I try to get back all the users that are receiver when the current user is a sender and vice versa.

The data in the database looks like this:
[Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRBFd.png)

The query looks like this:

```
        AppUser user = getAppUser(); //Gets the current user
        List<AppUser> list = new List<AppUser>(); //Wants users linked to current user

        try{
            List<Friend> asked = db.Friends.Where(x => x.receiver.Id == user.Id).ToList();
            foreach(Friend friend in asked){
                list.Add(friend.sender);
            }
        }
        catch{}

        try{
            List<Friend> sent = db.Friends.Where(x => x.sender.Id == user.Id).ToList();
            foreach (Friend friend in sent){
                list.Add(friend.receiver);
            }
        }
        catch{}
```

I tested as A with user A and B for all possible combinations. A => B, A => A, B => A, B => B. I should get back the result B, A, B, but instead I get the result null, A, null. When debugging, I get this (for asked):
[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5YIR.png)

The way I see it is that it sees the result as a null when the ApplicationUser is not the current user, but I have no clue of why. If I log in as the other user, I get the reverted result, so I still only see the results of the current user.

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: 1. Don't ever use `catch{}`. That's going to cause you massive headaches in the future. One day `list` will only be partially populated and you'll have a hell of a time figuring out why. 2. It's probably because you've got lazy loading turned off for `sender`. Is it marked as `virtual`?

Comment: Thank you Rob, that was indeed the mistake!